# Redirect root url to somewhere else in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes, root

I have routes like this:

```
map.namespace 'prepayments', :path_prefix => '/:locale/prepayments'  do |prepayment|
  prepayment.root  :controller => 'login', :namespace => 'prepayments'
  ...
end

map.redirect '/', :controller => 'prepayments/login' # this is not working
# I tried also
map.root :controller => 'prepayments/login'
```

What I would like to get is that after typing: www.example.com it would redirect me to www.example.com/en/prepayments.

Earlier when I used `map.root` from above example it just stayed at www.example.com and rendered correct view (but it was without `:locale` and it worked good), later I added `:locale` to my routes and from this time my view (that uses some form) doesn't work properly. I get error that it can't find corresponding route for form - which is right, because I didn't pass any `:locale`.

So, how to redirect root to another page? It will probably need to generate correct path and pass it through http 302.
Or/And how to make something like:

```
map.root :controller => 'prepayments/login', :my_locale => 'en'
```

EDIT:
My rake routes looks like this:

```
         prepayments_root  /:locale/prepayments               {:controller=>"prepayments/login", :action=>"index"}
       prepayments_create  /:locale/prepayments/send_email    {:method=>:post, :controller=>"prepayments/login", :action=>"send_email"}
         prepayments_home  /:locale/prepayments/home          {:controller=>"prepayments/prepayments", :action=>"home"}
         prepayments_save  /:locale/prepayments/save          {:controller=>"prepayments/prepayments", :action=>"save"}
        prepayments_agree  /:locale/prepayments/agree         {:controller=>"prepayments/prepayments", :action=>"agree"}
     prepayments_disagree  /:locale/prepayments/disagree      {:controller=>"prepayments/login", :action=>"logout"}
      prepayments_payment  /:locale/prepayments/payment       {:controller=>"prepayments/prepayments", :action=>"payment"}
prepayments_payment_email  /:locale/prepayments/payment_email {:controller=>"prepayments/prepayments", :action=>"payment_email"}
                           /:locale/prepayments/:uid          {:controller=>"prepayments/login", :action=>"verify"}
                 redirect  /                                  {:controller=>"prepayments/login", :action=>"index"}
```

EDIT:

I tried doing it in the way Garrett proposed and it worked. I changed routes:

```
map.redirect '/', :controller => 'prepayments/login', :action => 'welcome'
```

and added welcome method in controller:

```
def welcome
  redirect_to prepayments_root_path(:locale => 'en')
end
```

And it works as I wanted (so it changes url in my browser).

The other way is to change routes like this:

```
map.root :controller => 'prepayments/login', :locale => 'en'
```

It also works, but it isn't redirecting (it doesn't change url in browser). I'm not sure if there is such option as `map.redirect`. I found it in examples on www but I also found plugin that add such functionality.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score -8, accepted):

You will need to set the controller to a `Welcome` or what not, then when *that* controller is hit, it will redirect to the route you want. Maybe Rails 3 routing will be better for stuff like this, but for right now, you will need to have a main root controller.

Comment: But how add this :locale parameter to redirect_to prepayments_root_path ?

Comment: I know I can add it with some string before, but is there a nicer way?

Comment: Can you give output of your `rake routes`?

Comment: Obsolete answer. @glasz's one is the most complete and up to date.

Answer (score 157):

In Rails 3 you can write:

```
root :to => redirect('/prepayments')
```

The following page has a good introduction to doing these redirects in Rails 3: http://www.railsdispatch.com/posts/rails-routing

Comment: This uses a 301 permanent redirect.  How would you do a 302 temporary redirect?

Comment: I'm with @DerekDahmer!  How do you do a 302 from the routes.rb.  I tried passing in status: 302, but no joy.

Comment: Can you see if this answer does the trick? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19138779/99266

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection To do a temp (302) redirect, just add `status: 302` to the redirect directive: `get '/stories/:name', to: redirect('/articles/%{name}', status: 302)`

Comment: Still works as of Rails 6

Answer (score 39):

**root redirect options** don't seem to be [documented](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d98014cbcb0bf38f4ecd433d945047fc67fccc36/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/redirection.rb#L134) too well.
here you go (@derek, see last example):

**redirect to a subdomain on the current request's domain**

```
root to: redirect(subdomain: 'foo', path: '/bar') # => foo.example.com/bar
```

**redirect with substituted params from the matched route**

```
get 'stores/:name(*all)', to: redirect(subdomain: 'stores', path: '/%{name}%{all}')
```

**redirect with status code (eg. 302 instead of default 301)**

```
redirect(path: '/foo', status: 302)
```

**redirect with a conditional block**

```
redirect(status: 302) { |params, request|
  case request.host
  when 'localhost'
    '/foo'
  when /example.com$/
    '/bar'
  else
    '/baz'
  end
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Rails 4 (4.2.0 in my case), I added this: `match "*path" => "main#index", :via => [:get, :post]` to `app/config/routes.rb`.

To find out what you are supposed to put in place of `main`. Look in this file: `app/controllers/main_controller.rb`. Again, yours may not be called `main_controller.rb`, but it will be `something_controller.rb`, probably **NOT** `application_controller.rb` or `servers_controller.rb`. In that file, you'll see some code that looks like this:

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render :layout => "angular"
  end
end
```

Where there is **MainController**, you should be able to tell by the error message that rails provides in your browser what to do from here. Just replace *main* in `match "*path" => "main#index", :via => [:get, :post]` with whatever the prefix of the controller is.

Hope this makes sense. I am a ruby beginner as well