# How to redirect with a 301 or 302 in the routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can you redirect using a 302 from within the routes.rb file?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can pass in the status to the redirect in the route statement.  For example, to do a 302 redirect:

In the `routes.rb`

```
get '/old/path', to: redirect('/new/path', status: 302)
```

I hope this helps someone else!

Comment: it's also possible to write `get '/make_donation' => redirect('/new/path', status: 302)` which is a bit shorter

Comment: You can also write it in a more declarative manner
`get '/old/path', to: redirect('/new/path', status: :moved_permanently)`